# Run process that creates opportunity over night

Tags: apex

I have a custom object called `Calendar__c`. When I set a field on the calendar to `Status = Ready`, then I want to create a new opportunity with some fields filled in.

I need to ensure that this process is run overnight, but I am not sure where to start. I would be happy if someone could point me in the right direction, e.g. where I can find material to read up on this problem, but my google searches reveal no results. I guess I don't know the correct technical term of what I need to create.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000MICNIA4 Might be a good source to start.  Otherwise - if you want to tackle it more programatically, you can look for apex schedulable

Comment: @KoenCertyn : you should add this as an answer (or I will :D ). As this will give you more reputation and do more stuff on this forum.

Comment: @Mahmood I already did :)

Comment: Good for you. I wanted Koen get in there because he was the one with the comment and chance to get better reputation. :)

Comment: Here to help, not grinding rep :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways how this problem can be tackled.

1. Process Builder (configuration)

You would need to configure the Process Builder to have the action you want to occur in the future in the Scheduled Actions instead of the Immediate Actions. The Process Builder will still run when the edit is made to set the field value, but the action will not be carried out until the desired time based on the schedule that you set.

2. Apex Scheduled Job (code)

You can read more about Apex scheduler int he following link:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm